# HP Pavillion downgraded to XP, now no audio

Tags: windows-xp, audio, hp-pavilion

I recently reloaded this HP pavillion laptop dv2615nr with windows xp prof sp 2

I've basically thrown every single hp link at this thing to get the audio working.  From reloading several nvidia chipset drivers to every single convenant ac 97 audio driver linkd in the hp forum.

I got fedup and turned to cpuinfo which told me it was a wistron 30d6 motherboard with a nVidia nForce560 reva2 chipset.   Downloaded the correct nVidia driver and it got the sm bus controller, ethernet and wireless basically working fro mthe get go.  Now all thats left is the audio.  I installed the Microsoft UMM bus driver and every connexant AC 97 audio drivers on this laptop with the same error:

Driver Installation Failed: Could not find the MEDIA device for this driver.

I'm starting to think it has a completely different audio driver manufacturer all together since none of the Conexant drivers seem to work.  Any ideas how to figure this out?

UPDATE: just tried these tutorials..no luck with these either
http://forum.notebookreview.com/hp-compaq-voodoo-pc/200763-xp-up-running-99-9-my-new-dv6600-amd-nvidia-based.html
http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-17903-hp-pavilion-dv2000-drivers

Answer (score 2):

You can use HWINFO32 to discover exactly which chipset your audio is using.

Download from http://www.hwinfo.com/download32.html

Comment: tried it and the audio section says "unknown or none"

Answer (score 0):

HP offers very few drivers for your computer on XP, so your driver must come from Microsoft.

Try upgrading to XP SP3 and installing all Windows Updates, including optional ones, in the hope that this will bring a better audio driver for your card.

In any case, as XP SP2 support has ended on July 13, it's better to update.

Answer (score 0):

See the 3rd post ("part 3") in this thread for instructions and driver links on that model

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Operating-systems-and-software/General-XP-Downgrade-Guide-for-HP-Laptops/td-p/83267

You may have to start from scratch, reinstall XP clean then install the correct drivers in the correct order.

.